# Logic Proofs, Make an Outline for a very long statement help

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

[image: Picture of the problem]

This question has me pretty stumped, so far I only have:

Let a ∈ R+ be arbitrary, ?, let x ∈ R be arbitrary, assume that |x-1|is less than δ
What am I to do from here to continue with the outline?

Answer (score 0):

This is a proof of the uniform continuity of the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ at the point $x = 1$. Notice that since $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous on the closed interval $[0, 1]$, which is compact, it is also uniformly continuous on this interval, so it satisfies this hypothesis for all $x \in [0, 1]$. Thus we can assume that $x > 1$ (we ignore negative values as the square root function is not defined there). Let $ \epsilon > 0$. Since $x > \sqrt{x}$ for all $x > 1$, setting $\delta = \epsilon$ gives us that $$|x - 1| < \delta \Rightarrow |\sqrt{x} - 1| < |x - 1| = \delta = \epsilon,$$ thus for any $\epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 \, \big| \, |x - 1| < \delta \Rightarrow |\sqrt{x} - 1| < \epsilon, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.